# LINQ: Generate "AND" Expression instead of "OR" when using "CONTAINS"

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have this List:

```
string[] countries = {
        "USA",
        "CANADA"
    };
```

When I run this query :

```
query = (from user in db where
         user.Orders.Any(order => order.Price > 10 &&
                                      countries.Contains(order.DestinationCountry)))
```

Output is a list of users that have Orders sent to "USA" **OR** "Canada".

but I want the list of users that have Orders sent to both "USA" **AND**" "CANADA".

I can do this using below code but i'm searching for a pure linq solution without any **ForEach**:

```
foreach (country in countries) {
    query = (from user in query where
             user.Orders.Any(order => order.Price > 10 &&
                                      order.DestinationCountry == country));
}
```

**Answers:**

A. Using .Aggregate()

Generated query is just like For Each.

B.`where countries.All(c => user.Orders.Any(o => o.Price > 10 && o.DestinationCountry == c))`

When there is no element in Countries List (When I want all users based only on Price parameter), the result is not correct and other parameter is not considered!

---

*Update 1:*

I have tried **.All()** instead of **.Contains()** before posting and it returns 0 users.

*Update 2:*

I have updated my question to make it closer to the real problem.

lets say Country is not the only parameter.

*Update 3:*

Checked some answers and added the result to my question.

Comment: Just for clarity, what if a user has orders sent to both US and Canada and some other country, do you still want that user? Meaning, do you want users where orders are sent to **only** US or Canada, or users that have orders sent to US, and orders sent to Canada (and disregarding whether or not that user also has orders sent anywhere else)?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen They should have orders sent to both US AND CANADA. If they have orders sent to another country, it is OK and it doesn't matter.

Comment: Both my answer with `.Aggregate` and Douglas / Jon Skeet's functionally identical answers using `countries.All` behave just like your `foreach` version: that also doesn't do any filtering on price if there are no countries. Can you update that to more closely correspond to what you want to accomplish? It's not clear to me what results you are expecting. It is clear in some specific cases, but not what the general logic should be.

Answer (score 3):

So you want a list of the users such that all the countries in the list are present in the set of order destinations?

Logically, that would be:

```
query = from user in db
        where countries.All(c => user.Orders.Any(o => o.DestinationCountry == c))
        select ...;
```

However, I'm not confident that EF will do what you want with that. It's not clear to me what the right SQL query would be to start with - in a simple way, at least.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks a lot for your answer. I have updated my question. Do you think this solution works if there is any other parameter involved?

Comment: @AfshinGh Why wouldn't it? I don't know if this answer works (for the same reason already mentioned in this answer), but I don't see why any additional filter would make any difference here.

Comment: @AfshinGh: What hvd said, basically :)

Comment: @JonSkeet When there is no element in CountriesList (When I want all users based on other parameter and this parameter is not needed), the result is not correct and other parameter is not considered!

Comment: @AfshinGh: This is the first you've mentioned about the situation where the list of countries is empty. You might want to consider just using a separate query for that situation.

Answer (score 3):

```
query = 
    db.Users.Where(user =>
        countries.All(country =>
            user.Orders.Any(order => 
                order.DestinationCountry == country)))
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I have updated my question. Do you think this solution works if there is any other parameter involved?

Comment: When there is no element in CountriesList (When I want all users based on other parameter and this parameter is not needed), the result is not correct and other parameter is not considered!

Comment: My answer was intended for the original version of your question. You might want to open another question, with a proper formulation of your full requirements, if you want a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
query = (from user in db where
     user.Orders
     .Where(o => countries.Contains(o.DestinationCountry))
     .GroupBy(o => o.DestinationCountry)
     .Count() == countries.Count
);
```

The idea is to keep only the orders going to countries of interest, then group by country, and check that the number of groups equals the number of countries.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I'm trying to avoid GroupBy if possible. I have updated my question. Do you think this solution works if there is any other parameter involved?

Comment: @AfshinGh: *Why* are you trying to avoid `GroupBy`? Have you tried it and found the query to be too slow for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using [`Enumerable.Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549218%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
query = countries.Aggregate(query,
  (q, c) =>
  from user in q
  where user.Orders.Any(order => order.DestinationCountry == c)
  select user);
```

but really, this is harder to understand than your `foreach` loop, so I'd just go with that.

Note that although I refer to a member of `Enumerable`, that member of `Enumerable` is actually building up an `IQueryable<User>` query chain just like your `foreach` loop, so this will not cause the filtering to move to the client.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. As you said, it looks like ForEach and all of the data is going to be moved to client. So I think ForEach is better.

Comment: @AfshinGh No, I do think `foreach` is better for readability, but not for correctness: they do exactly the same thing, and both cause the filtering to be performed server-side. There's a "not" in my last sentence that I think you missed. :)

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll try this and compare generated query against other answer. thanks.

Comment: Generated query is just like ForEach. Thanks.